# The Mean Value Theorem on convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

I'm reading about the proof of Helly's Intersection Theorem:

> [image]

I'm unable to understand the reasoning behind the argument

> If $n=2,$ the set $C_{n} \cup C_{-n}$ is convex, so by the Mean Value Theorem it must contain a point in $H$...

Could you please elaborate on how we obtain the contradiction? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the mean value theorem that is being used, it is the intermediate value theorem.

Let $x_1 \in C_n$ and $x_2 \in C_{-n}$. Since $C_n \cup C_{-n}$ is convex, we have a path $p:[0,1] \to C_n \cup C_{-n}$ connecting both. The function $f \circ p$, where $f(x)=\langle x , y\rangle$, is then a real continuous function which is greater than $a$ at $1$ and smaller than $a$ at $0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $t_0$ such that $(f \circ p)(t_0)=a$, i.e., $\langle p(t_0), y \rangle = a$. This point $p(t_0)$ is by definition in $H$.

Comment: Did you meant the function $p$ is defined by $p(t) = tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ for all $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @Akira Yes. (Actually, to be consistent with how I phrased things, it should be $p(t)=(1-t)x_1+tx_2$.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your very prompt reply :))) I very appreciate your kindness.

Comment: Could you please explain how we get the contradiction from $K \cap H=\emptyset$, $K \cap C_{n} \neq \emptyset$ and $K \cap C_{-n} \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @Akira $K$ is convex, being the intersection of convex sets. Since $K \cap C_n \neq \emptyset$ and $K \cap C_{-n} \neq \emptyset$, we can pick $x_1 \in K \cap C_n$ and $x_2 \in K \cap C_{-n}$ and repeat the argument in the answer to arrive at a point $p(t_0)$ in $K$ such that $\langle p(t_0) , y \rangle =a$. Then, such $p(t_0)$ is in $K$ and $H$, contradicting the fact that $K \cap H = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it ^^

Comment: Hi Aloizio, to apply the inductive hypothesis, we must have $D_{i}=C_{i} \cap H \neq \emptyset$. I don't know how to obtain it. Could you please elaborate more?